# Magento 2 Review / Ratings Stars ICONS are not correct showing in frontpage

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, review

we have Magento 2.1.2 with a Custom LUMA Parent Theme.
The Rating Stars are not correctly showing.

[image]

If i hover the "stars" the show me the red stars over the arrow but i need only stars not arrows!

Sombody here, how can help me to fix thats Problem?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue, the **:before** pseudo class for `.review-control-vote` has the wrong icon being called in the **_module.less** file.

In `app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/web/css/source/_variables.less` **line 30**

change

`@icon-star-empty: '\e625';`

to

`@icon-star-empty: '\e605';`

> Ideally, this should be within your own theme and you shouldn't be
>   editing the Luma theme directly.